# Подтверждение регистрации email кодом

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

При нажатии на кнопку отправить код, приходит код вот в таком виде + информация отправителя

"Ваш временный код: LhWA2E"

вот php код который реализует регистрацию и эту функцию
После того как приходит код, появляется поле для его ввода , и как бы я не вводил, код всегда оказывается не верным. В чем может быть проблема?

```
  <?php
    function generateCode($length = 6) {
        $characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        $code = "";

        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $code .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
        }

        return $code;
    }

    // Проверяем, была ли отправлена форма с почтой
    if (isset($_POST['get_code'])) {
        $mail = $_POST['mail'];

        if (empty($mail)) {
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>Пожалуйста, введите почту</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";
        } else {
            // Проверяем существование пользователя с такой почтой в базе данных
            $checkQuery = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE mail = '$mail'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $checkQuery);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                echo "<table>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>Пользователь с такой почтой уже зарегистрирован</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</table>";
            } else {
                // Генерация и отправка кода на почту
                $code = generateCode(6);

                $to = $mail;
                $subject = "Временный код регистрации";
                $message = "Ваш временный код: $code";
                $headers = "From: ...";

                if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
                    // Сохранение кода в базе данных, чтобы можно было проверить его в следующем шаге
                    $codeQuery = "INSERT INTO verification_codes (mail, code) VALUES ('$mail', '$code')";
                    mysqli_query($conn, $codeQuery);

                    // Показать поле для ввода кода и кнопку для регистрации
                    echo '<form method="POST" action="" name="go">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="code" name="code" placeholder="Код">



                              <button type="submit" name="go" class="btn btn-primary">Зарегистрироваться</button>
                          </form>';
                } else {
                    echo "<table>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>Не удалось отправить код на почту</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</table>";
                }
            }
        }
    }

// Проверяем, была ли отправлена форма с кодом и почтой
if (isset($_POST['go'])) {
    $code = $_POST['code'];
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];

    // Проверяем, соответствует ли введенный код тому, который был отправлен на почту
$checkCodeQuery = "SELECT * FROM verification_codes WHERE mail = '$mail' AND code = '$code'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $checkCodeQuery);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // Код верный, регистрируем пользователя
    $registerQuery = "INSERT INTO users (mail) VALUES ('$mail')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $registerQuery);

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Пользователь успешно зарегистрирован</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    // Код некорректный, выдаем ошибку
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Неверный код</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}}
    elseif (isset($_POST['go'])) {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $fullname = $_POST["fullname"];
        $mail = $_POST["mail"];
        $pass = $_POST["pass"];

        if (empty($name) || empty($fullname) || empty($mail) || empty($pass)) {
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>Нужно заполнить все поля для регистрации</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";
        } else {
            // Проверяем существование пользователя с такой почтой в базе данных
            $checkQuery = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE mail = '$mail'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $checkQuery);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                $query = "INSERT INTO users (id, name, fullname, mail, pass, adres) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$fullname', '$mail', '$pass' ,'$adres');";
                mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            }
        }
    }
   ?>
```

И HTML код к которому привязан php

```
<form class="LogForm" method="post">
  <div class="soForm">
    <div class="row mb-4">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-outline">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
            name="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="<?= isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '' ?>">
          <label class="form-label" for="form3Example1">Имя</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-outline">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" name="fullname" value="<?= isset($_POST['fullname']) ? $_POST['fullname'] : '' ?>">
          <label class="form-label" for="form3Example2">Фамилия</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-outline mb-4">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mail" name="mail" value="<?= isset($_POST['mail']) ? $_POST['mail'] : '' ?>">
      <label class="form-label" for="form3Example3">Почта</label>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" name='get_code' class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-4">Отправить код</button>

    <div class="form-outline mb-4">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" name="pass">
      <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4">Пароль</label>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Начать стоит с исправления sql-инъекций

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

Давайте сперва немного упростим ваш код. PHP позволяет опередять функции и обычно код распроложенный в услоиви или в цикле — хороший кандидат на выделение в функцию (продробнее об это почитайте в книге Совершенный код Стива Макконнелла).

```php
function userExists(string $mail): bool {
    // ...
}

function sendMail(string $mail, string $code): bool {
    // ...
}

function saveCode(string $code) {
    // ...
}

function codeIsCorrect(string $mail, string $code): bool {
    // ...
}
```

С выводом html-кода поступим ещё круче — подключим отдельные файлы через require

```php
<!-- emptyEmail.phtml -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Пожалуйста, введите почту</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```php
if (empty($mail)) {
    require './emptyEmail.phtml';
    exit(0); // и если уж на этом обработка закончена, то выйдем
}
```

В итоге получится более структурированный и понятный код, который можно подебажить хотя бы и с помощью var_dump (просто выводите значения переменных в тех участка кода, где у вас возникают сомнения по поводу их значений).

Некоторые ошибки даже дебажить не придётся, так как они сами бросятся в глаза. Например:

```php
<?php

// ...

if (userExists($mail)) {
    registerNewUser(...);
}
```

---

### На заметку

С тривиальной задачей поиска багов в php-коде вы справитесь. Но могут быть баги поинтереснее. Например: если вы используете MySQL и создавали поле `code` как текст с collation ...**_ci**, то при сопоставлении кода не будет учитываться регистр. То есть код FooBarBaz подойдёт и для foobarbaz. Новички часто забывают об этом. Обязательно протестируйте этот кейс.